# Backend for an android app

Tags: android, backend

I am developing an android app for test conduction, and I am looking for a reliable backend site that will help me start from scratch. I tried using back{4}app but I can't create a new parse app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try not to use parse. They are shutting down. Try to write a native app. You can have a look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To start from scratch with `back{4}app` you simple have to signUp at https://www.back4app.com/
Once the login is done you are redirected to the dashboard https://dashboard.back4app.com/apps 
Here simply click the Button `"Build new Parse app"` and follow the instructions